# Loading pendrive sectors

Tags: bios, interrupt, usb-drive

How can we load sectors of the pendrive using bios interrupts??
Having low level disk access is needed for booting from the pendirve....
I got to hear that, we can use int **13h** to load sectors...but how to use the same interrupts to  load sectors of a pendrive?? what are the parameters required to load the sectors......???
How can we load a sector, say *2560* of a pendrive...
How to calculate the disk parameters to be used for the int 13h ??
How to get the cylinder , track numbers for a pendrive?????

Answer (score 1):

If the BIOS can boot a pen drive then the BIOS is emulating a hard drive or floppy drive for the pen drive.  int 13h with AH=48h or AH=08h asks the BIOS for the geometry of the emulated hard drive or floppy drive.